# How to integrate java api in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am new in ExtJs I am trying to integrate java API to save record in extJs but it gives error. i.e.

> Ext.form.Basic.updateRecord(): A record is required.Please find My code details

```js
onSaveClick: function (button) {
       
        var dialog, record, store;
        dialog = button.up('window').down('form');
        dialog.updateRecord();
        record = dialog.getRecord();
        
        if (record === trac.app.getUser()) {
            record.save();
        } else {
            store = Ext.getStore('Routes');
            if (record.phantom) {
                store.add(record);
            }
            store.sync({
                failure: function (batch) {
                    store.rejectChanges();
                    trac.app.showError(batch.exceptions[0].getError().response);
                }
            });
        }
        button.up('window').close();      
    }
```

Comment: Seems that you have to pass record as parameter. Are you sure you have java, not javascript?

Comment: Yes i am using javascript, i updated my code, can you please help me !!

Answer (score 0):

First get the record, then use it as a parameter to dialog.updateRecord:

```
onSaveClick: function (button) {

    var dialog, record, store;
    dialog = button.up('window').down('form');
    record = dialog.getRecord();
    dialog.updateRecord(record);

    if (record === trac.app.getUser()) {
        record.save();
    } else {
        store = Ext.getStore('Routes');
        if (record.phantom) {
            store.add(record);
        }
        store.sync({
            failure: function (batch) {
                store.rejectChanges();
                trac.app.showError(batch.exceptions[0].getError().response);
            }
        });
    }
    button.up('window').close();      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just read the [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.form.Basic.html#method-updateRecord):

> Persists the values in this form into the passed Ext.data.Model object in a beginEdit/endEdit block. If the record is not specified, it will attempt to update ( **if it exists** ) the record provided to loadRecord.

which might explain, why the other answer is slightly pointless (trying to get a record, which was most likely never loaded from a store. most likely even no-op, because it's get/set of the same thing). the proper application of the method isn't even onsave, but onload ...eg. to populate the form with `Ext.data.Model`, independently from a bound store.